# How to get previous state of a tracked entity in dbcontext after savechanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, dbcontext

When we are working with DbContext it tracks what happens to the entities attached to it.

If you modify a property, an entry will be added to ChangeTracker.Entries with EntityState.Modified, the same happens when you add or delete entites, they will be sent to ChangeTracker with a State EntityState.Added or EntityState.Deleted;

A way to get the entries by state:

```
private List<EntityEntry> GetChangesByType(params EntityState[] states)
{
     var entries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries();
     return entries.Where(x => states.Contains(x.State)).ToList();
}
```

I need to log these entries with the operation that is occurring to them, but In case of adding an entity I will not have the Id, so I need to perform a savechanges before log, but when savechanges in called, it moves all tracked entries to EntityState.Unchanged, by doing this I can't know the previous state of these entries.

Is there a way to get the previous state, or another solution to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the entries before the `SaveChanges` and process them after - they will contain the updated ids. For example:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entries = GetChangesByType(...);

    var result = base.SaveChanges();

    // process/log the entries, which will have ids filled
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Worked =], I just used a Dictionary<EntityState, List<EntityEntry>>, savechanges will change state of each entry to Unchanged, But with dictionary I categorize entries by previous state. ty.